Sympy's `subs` function does not work correctly with `exp`
I use SymPy to compute exp(U), where U is a matrix of symbols.
Then, I want to substitute the symbols in U for values, but SymPy gives me the wrong result.
Below is a minimal code example:
from sympy import *

var("u0, u1, u2, u3", complex=True)
U = Matrix([[u0, u1], [u2, u3]])
x1 = exp(U.subs({u0: 1, u1: 0, u2: 0, u3: -1}))
x2 = exp(U).subs({u0: 1, u1: 0, u2: 0, u3: -1})
display(x1)    # [[e, 0], [0, exp(-1)]]
display(x2)    # [[0, 0], [0, exp(-1)]]
assert x1.equals(x2)

This example should compute

however, when I substitute U after computing exp(U) I get the wrong result.
Does anybody know a trick to make my example work?
I'd like to substitute U after computing exp(U).
I've seen many posts about SymPy's subs function not working as expected, but didn't find a solution for my case.

The expression generated by exp(U) is messy:
In [117]: exp(U)
Out[117]: 
⎡                                    _______________________________                                                     _______________________________                                                                                             _______________________________                                                                                                                                                                                          _______________________________⎤
⎢                                   ╱   2                         2                                                     ╱   2                         2                                                                                             ╱   2                         2                                                                                                                                                                                          ╱   2                         2 ⎥
⎢                       u₀   u₃   ╲╱  u₀  - 2⋅u₀⋅u₃ + 4⋅u₁⋅u₂ + u₃                                          u₀   u₃   ╲╱  u₀  - 2⋅u₀⋅u₃ + 4⋅u₁⋅u₂ + u₃                                                                                  u₀   u₃   ╲╱  u₀  - 2⋅u₀⋅u₃ + 4⋅u₁⋅u₂ + u₃                                                                                                                                                                               u₀   u₃   ╲╱  u₀  - 2⋅u₀⋅u₃ + 4⋅u₁⋅u₂ + u₃  ⎥
⎢                       ── + ── - ──────────────────────────────────                                        ── + ── + ──────────────────────────────────                                                                                ── + ── + ──────────────────────────────────                                                            ⎛                      _______________________________                         _______________________________⎞  ── + ── - ──────────────────────────────────⎥
⎢                       2    2                    2                                                         2    2                    2                                                                                           2     2    2                    2                                                                             ⎜  2                  ╱   2                         2                2        ╱   2                         2 ⎟  2    2                    2                 ⎥
⎢              2⋅u₁⋅u₂⋅ℯ                                                                           2⋅u₁⋅u₂⋅ℯ                                                                                                                  4⋅u₁ ⋅u₂⋅ℯ                                                                                                   2⋅u₁⋅⎝u₀  - 2⋅u₀⋅u₃ + u₀⋅╲╱  u₀  - 2⋅u₀⋅u₃ + 4⋅u₁⋅u₂ + u₃   + 2⋅u₁⋅u₂ + u₃  - u₃⋅╲╱  u₀  - 2⋅u₀⋅u₃ + 4⋅u₁⋅u₂ + u₃  ⎠⋅ℯ                                            ⎥
⎢───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── - ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────  - ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── - ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────⎥
⎢⎛             _______________________________⎞    _______________________________   ⎛             _______________________________⎞    _______________________________    ⎛             _______________________________⎞ ⎛                      _______________________________                         _______________________________⎞     ⎛             _______________________________⎞ ⎛                      _______________________________                         _______________________________⎞  ⎥
⎢⎜            ╱   2                         2 ⎟   ╱   2                         2    ⎜            ╱   2                         2 ⎟   ╱   2                         2     ⎜            ╱   2                         2 ⎟ ⎜  2                  ╱   2                         2                2        ╱   2                         2 ⎟     ⎜            ╱   2                         2 ⎟ ⎜  2                  ╱   2                         2                2        ╱   2                         2 ⎟  ⎥
⎢⎝u₀ - u₃ + ╲╱  u₀  - 2⋅u₀⋅u₃ + 4⋅u₁⋅u₂ + u₃  ⎠⋅╲╱  u₀  - 2⋅u₀⋅u₃ + 4⋅u₁⋅u₂ + u₃     ⎝u₀ - u₃ - ╲╱  u₀  - 2⋅u₀⋅u₃ + 4⋅u₁⋅u₂ + u₃  ⎠⋅╲╱  u₀  - 2⋅u₀⋅u₃ + 4⋅u₁⋅u₂ + u₃      ⎝u₀ - u₃ - ╲╱  u₀  - 2⋅u₀⋅u₃ + 4⋅u₁⋅u₂ + u₃  ⎠⋅⎝u₀  - 2⋅u₀⋅u₃ + u₀⋅╲╱  u₀  - 2⋅u₀⋅u₃ + 4⋅u₁⋅u₂ + u₃   + 4⋅u₁⋅u₂ + u₃  - u₃⋅╲╱  u₀  - 2⋅u₀⋅u₃ + 4⋅u₁⋅u₂ + u₃  ⎠     ⎝u₀ - u₃ + ╲╱  u₀  - 2⋅u₀⋅u₃ + 4⋅u₁⋅u₂ + u₃  ⎠⋅⎝u₀  - 2⋅u₀⋅u₃ + u₀⋅╲╱  u₀  - 2⋅u₀⋅u₃ + 4⋅u₁⋅u₂ + u₃   + 4⋅u₁⋅u₂ + u₃  - u₃⋅╲╱  u₀  - 2⋅u₀⋅u₃ + 4⋅u₁⋅u₂ + u₃  ⎠  ⎥
⎢                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            ⎥
⎢                                                   _______________________________                    _______________________________                                                                                                                _______________________________                                                                                                                                                             _______________________________                            ⎥
⎢                                                  ╱   2                         2                    ╱   2                         2                                                                                                                ╱   2                         2                                                                                                                                                             ╱   2                         2                             ⎥
⎢                                      u₀   u₃   ╲╱  u₀  - 2⋅u₀⋅u₃ + 4⋅u₁⋅u₂ + u₃         u₀   u₃   ╲╱  u₀  - 2⋅u₀⋅u₃ + 4⋅u₁⋅u₂ + u₃                                                                                                     u₀   u₃   ╲╱  u₀  - 2⋅u₀⋅u₃ + 4⋅u₁⋅u₂ + u₃                                                                                                                                                  u₀   u₃   ╲╱  u₀  - 2⋅u₀⋅u₃ + 4⋅u₁⋅u₂ + u₃                              ⎥
⎢                                      ── + ── - ──────────────────────────────────       ── + ── + ──────────────────────────────────                                                                                                   ── + ── + ──────────────────────────────────                               ⎛                      _______________________________                         _______________________________⎞  ── + ── - ──────────────────────────────────                            ⎥
⎢                                      2    2                    2                        2    2                    2                                                                                                                    2    2                    2                                                ⎜  2                  ╱   2                         2                2        ╱   2                         2 ⎟  2    2                    2                                             ⎥
⎢                                  u₂⋅ℯ                                               u₂⋅ℯ                                                                                                                                      2⋅u₁⋅u₂⋅ℯ                                                                           ⎝u₀  - 2⋅u₀⋅u₃ + u₀⋅╲╱  u₀  - 2⋅u₀⋅u₃ + 4⋅u₁⋅u₂ + u₃   + 2⋅u₁⋅u₂ + u₃  - u₃⋅╲╱  u₀  - 2⋅u₀⋅u₃ + 4⋅u₁⋅u₂ + u₃  ⎠⋅ℯ                                                                        ⎥
⎢                                - ──────────────────────────────────────────────── + ────────────────────────────────────────────────                                                              ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── + ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────                            ⎥
⎢                                            _______________________________                    _______________________________                                                                                           _______________________________                         _______________________________                                                 _______________________________                         _______________________________                                                    ⎥
⎢                                           ╱   2                         2                    ╱   2                         2                                                                        2                  ╱   2                         2                2        ╱   2                         2                              2                  ╱   2                         2                2        ╱   2                         2                                                     ⎥
⎣                                         ╲╱  u₀  - 2⋅u₀⋅u₃ + 4⋅u₁⋅u₂ + u₃                   ╲╱  u₀  - 2⋅u₀⋅u₃ + 4⋅u₁⋅u₂ + u₃                                                                       u₀  - 2⋅u₀⋅u₃ + u₀⋅╲╱  u₀  - 2⋅u₀⋅u₃ + 4⋅u₁⋅u₂ + u₃   + 4⋅u₁⋅u₂ + u₃  - u₃⋅╲╱  u₀  - 2⋅u₀⋅u₃ + 4⋅u₁⋅u₂ + u₃                             u₀  - 2⋅u₀⋅u₃ + u₀⋅╲╱  u₀  - 2⋅u₀⋅u₃ + 4⋅u₁⋅u₂ + u₃   + 4⋅u₁⋅u₂ + u₃  - u₃⋅╲╱  u₀  - 2⋅u₀⋅u₃ + 4⋅u₁⋅u₂ + u₃                                                      ⎦

This expression is valid for generic values of the symbols u0,u1,u2,u3. The values you are substituting in correspond to a degenerate case. The result should be nan because the expression evaluates to zero divided by zero for these values. Performing the substitutions one by one in a different order shows this:
In [79]: exp(U).subs(u0,1).subs(u3,-1).subs(u2,0)
Out[79]: 
⎡nan  nan⎤
⎢        ⎥
⎢      -1⎥
⎣ 0   ℯ  ⎦

A quirk in the substitution causes the expressions to simplify to zero instead of nan because the numerators become zero before it is noticed that the denominators are also zero for the given values:
In [118]: exp(U).subs({u0: 1, u1: 0, u2: 0, u3: -1})
Out[118]: 
⎡0   0 ⎤
⎢      ⎥
⎢    -1⎥
⎣0  ℯ  ⎦

In [119]: exp(U).subs(u0,1).subs(u1,0).subs(u2,0).subs(u3,-1)
Out[119]: 
⎡0   0 ⎤
⎢      ⎥
⎢    -1⎥
⎣0  ℯ  ⎦

A simultaneous substitution reveals the problem:
In [88]: exp(U).subs({u0: 1, u1: 0, u2: 0, u3: -1}, simultaneous=True)
Out[88]: 
⎡nan  nan⎤
⎢        ⎥
⎢      -1⎥
⎣ 0   ℯ  ⎦

In [89]: exp(U).xreplace({u0: 1, u1: 0, u2: 0, u3: -1})
Out[89]: 
⎡nan  nan⎤
⎢        ⎥
⎢      -1⎥
⎣ 0   ℯ  ⎦

The expression for exp(U) is valid provided that u1 != 0 and u2 != 0 i.e. that the matrix is not triangular and also provided that the matrix does not have a repeated eigenvalue i.e. provided u0**2 - 2*u0*u3 + 4*u1*u2 + u3**2 != 0. The repeated eigenvalues case is something like:
In [111]: exp(U).subs({u0:-2, u1:1, u2:-1, u3:-4})
Out[111]: 
⎡nan  nan⎤
⎢        ⎥
⎣nan  nan⎦

In [112]: exp(U.subs({u0:-2, u1:1, u2:-1, u3:-4}))
Out[112]: 
⎡   -3   -3⎤
⎢2⋅ℯ    ℯ  ⎥
⎢          ⎥
⎢  -3      ⎥
⎣-ℯ      0 ⎦

Other special cases will have other forms:
In [90]: exp(U.subs(u1,0)).simplify()
Out[90]: 
⎡      u₀           ⎤
⎢     ℯ           0 ⎥
⎢                   ⎥
⎢   ⎛ u₀    u₃⎞     ⎥
⎢u₂⋅⎝ℯ   - ℯ  ⎠   u₃⎥
⎢──────────────  ℯ  ⎥
⎣   u₀ - u₃         ⎦

In [91]: exp(U.subs(u1,0).subs(u2,0))
Out[91]: 
⎡ u₀     ⎤
⎢ℯ     0 ⎥
⎢        ⎥
⎢      u₃⎥
⎣ 0   ℯ  ⎦

The first of these is valid for u1 == 0 and u0 != u3. The second of these is valid for u1 == 0 and u2 == 0.
This one is valid for u1 == 0 and u0 == u3:
In [92]: exp(U.subs(u1,0).subs(u3,u0)).simplify()
Out[92]: 
⎡  u₀       ⎤
⎢ ℯ       0 ⎥
⎢           ⎥
⎢    u₀   u₀⎥
⎣u₂⋅ℯ    ℯ  ⎦

As you can see there are lots of different degenerate cases. The expression returned by exp(U) represents the generic case i.e. for almost all possible values of the symbols it is correct. Making expressions that are valid for every possible degenerate case is difficult and also not usually what is wanted because it would be a big mess of piecewise expressions.
You could use e.g. simultaneous substitution and check for nan as a simple way to detect whether your values represent a degenerate case:
In [95]: exp(U).xreplace({u0: 1, u1: 0, u2: 0, u3: -1}).has(nan)
Out[95]: True

